# Does $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-1)$ converge in distribution?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, convergence

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and consider, for each $n$, independent real valued stochastic variables $Z_{1n}\ldots Z_{nn}$, such that
$$
    P(Z_{nk}=n)=1-P(Z_{nk}=0)=\frac{1}{n}
$$
for $k=1,\ldots,n$. Thus $Z_{nk}$ takes on almost surely the two values $n$ and $0$. Define
$$
    Y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_{nk}
 $$

see that $\mathbb{E}Z_{nk}=np=n\frac{1}{n}=1$. The we use that the expectations of sums is equal to the sums of expectations, so

$$
    \mathbb{E}Y_n=\mathbb{E} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n Z_{nk}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}Z_{nk}=\frac{1}{n}n=1
$$
We also see that $VZ_{nk}=np(1-p)=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Further. Since all the $Z_{nk}$'s are uncorrelated, we have that the variance of the sum, is equal to the sum of the variances.
$$
    VY_n=V \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n Z_{nk}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n VZ_{nk}=\frac{1}{n}n(1-\frac{1}{n})=\frac{n-1}{n}
$$

Further. From the central limit theorem we know that 
$$
P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i-\xi}{\sigma} \leq x\right)\rightarrow \Phi(x)
$$

> How do I show that the distribution of $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-1)\xrightarrow{D}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Comment: can you derive the characteristic or the moment generating function of $Y_n$?

Comment: Did you mean to define$Y_n$ as $\displaystyle Y_n=\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^nZ_{nk}$ instead of as $\displaystyle Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^nZ_{nk}$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes. I have corrected that.

Comment: @StasK it is not part of the curriculum. So I am not sure.

Comment: @RudFaden, this is your educational opportunity, then. Usually, chfs and mgfs are the easiest tool to study convergence in distribution. I would not ask my students to establish convergence in distribution without equipping them these tools. Characteristic functions require complex analysis, and moment generating functions, only calculus.

Comment: @StasK If the OP hasn't got an introduction to those tools, it is maybe just a basic statistics class. As a result, it may be enough to apply just one of the central limit theorems here.

Comment: @random_guy, may be. But it is still an unbalanced basic stats class if they teach weak convergence. A clarification to the OP, then, stands: what are the tools that they have at their disposal to demonstrate convergence in distribution?

Comment: @StasK and other curious people. It is a measure theory class. We just proved the CLT (Lindberg proof) and been shown a few examples. I think the solution is just to plus the mean and variance of $Y_n$ into the CLT and then show that it becomes $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-1)$. But I can't really get it to fit though.

Comment: Ah-h-h... I smell Billingsley here. I [never liked](http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Theory-Universitext-Alexandr-Borovkov/dp/144715200X) the Lindberg proof, the characteristic functions proof is so much cuter and more compact... shows the beauty of math rather than the tediousness of measure theory. @RudFaden, can you please go back and edit your question to include the full formulation of the CLT as was just proved in your class?

Comment: I would have thought $Y_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_{nk}$ had a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p=\frac1n$.  Since $np=1$ is a constant, $Y_n\xrightarrow{D}$ a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=1$.

Comment: There is a convergence in distribution from Poisson distributions to normal distributions: if $X_n$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=n$ then $\frac{X_n-n}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.  But I do not see how that fits here

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your indices are overdefined, since you only ever sum $Z_{kn}$ over $k$.  So I'm going to simplify your problem by just referring to these as $Z_k$.  Now, define $X_{k} \sim \text{IID Bern}(1/n)$ and $Z_{k} = n X_{k}$ so that you're now dealing with standard indicator variables.  You then have:

$$Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n Z_{k} = \sum_{k=1}^n X_{k} \sim \text{Bin}(n,1/n).$$

Your mean and variance formulae follow directly from this known distribution.  The asymptotic mean and variance of $Y_n$ is unity, and from the CLT we have:

$$Y_n \xrightarrow{D} \text{N}(1,1).$$

This is a different asymptotic result from the one you conjectured.